# Can you learn react before JavaScript

Tags: reactjs

I am planning to learn react.js before JavaScript. I know that react is built off of js, but would there be any problems if i just jump straight into react?

Comment: Why all the hate on this question? A naive question, yes. But an innocent one.

Comment: @Andrew yeh not sure why theres so much hate for this question. Just wanna learn to code lol. The stackoverflow community doesn't feel as friendly as i thought it would be.

Comment: Well, that being said, yes. learn JavaScript first. If you already know another language, it shouldn't be too difficult. I highly recommend javascript.info . I loved reading it. Part 2 you don't need to fully digest, but you should have a general understanding. React handles all DOM traversal for you.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, thats kinda what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't learn React before JavaScript. React is a JS library.

From React documentation on "[A Note on JavaScript](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html#a-note-on-javascript)":

> React is a JavaScript library, and so it assumes you have a basic
>   understanding of the JavaScript language. If you don’t feel very
>   confident, we recommend refreshing your JavaScript knowledge so you
>   can follow along more easily.

Answer (score -2):

One thing I learned as a student who likes to jump around from one topic to the next, is that a lot of times while you are coding a project, it's going to get stuck at some point.  If you don't understand what is coded in whatever library of code, that you're using, you won't know how to fix it.  I agree, you should learn JavaScript before React.

Comment: May be a comment not answer.